# Passing and referring to column name in a function

Tags: r, function

I want to pass and then perform a simple swap on column values with a function.

```
Fix_Entries <- function(Column){
  df$Column[which(df$Column == "-")] <- "Y"
}
```

However, I keep getting errors, and I can't find any reference to help me solve this!

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Column, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 8460
```

Comment: Could you update your post with `dput(head(yourdataset))`

Comment: I can't post that information, because it is PHI. What in particular are you looking for?

Comment: Just wanted to know the structure of the dataset.  If it is similar structure as the one I showed in my example, it would work.  Can you try this `sum(df1$yourcolumnName == "-")` and `sum(trimws(df1$yourcolumnName) == "-")`  If there are leading/lagging spaces, it wouldn't work as `==` is fixed match, one option is `trimws` to remove those spaces from the start and end.  Another is `sum(grepl("-", df1$yourcolumnName))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are `Column` as a string, then use `[[` and also return the dataset.  It may be also better to have the dataset identifier as another argument

```
Fix_Entries <- function(df, Column){
   df[[Column]][which(df[[Column]] == "-")] <- "Y"
   df
}

df1 <- Fix_Entries(df1, "Col1")
df1
#   Col1       Col2
#1     N  2.2088619
#2 Hello  1.9015173
#3     A -0.0708413
#4     B -0.2253454
#5     Y -0.2403291
#6     C  0.8615449
#7     Y -0.5985272
```

---

This can also be achieved with `tidyverse` by taking unquoted column name as input

```
Fix_Entries_tidy <- function(df, Column) {
       Column <- enquo(Column)
       df  %>%
           mutate(!! Column :=  replace(!! Column, !!Column == "-", "Y"))
}
Fix_Entries_tidy(df1, Col1)
#  Col1       Col2
#1     N  2.2088619
#2 Hello  1.9015173
#3     A -0.0708413
#4     B -0.2253454
#5     Y -0.2403291
#6     C  0.8615449
#7     Y -0.5985272
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(Col1 = c("N", "Hello", "A", "B", "-", "C", "-"),
       Col2 = rnorm(7), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I've tried that, but for some reason it doesn't work. When I look at the values in the column afterwards, I still see "-", and I don't see any "Y".

Comment: @JPreisser  I showed with a reproducible example.  You need to do assignment `df1 <- Fix_Entries(df1, "Col1")`  It is not inplace assignment inside a function and inside the function, there are minimal side-effects unlike in python

Comment: I should have specified that I am calling the function with a string, e.g. Fix_Entries("BMI"). I ran your code, but I still have "-" when I look at df1 afterwards.

Comment: @JPreisser  Please try with the example in my `data` and check how your dataset is different from that data with `str(df1)`.  Also, if you are not updating the dataset i.e. `df1 <- Fix_Entries(df1, "Col1")`, the original object wouldn't get updated

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, but while your code works for df1, it doesn't work for the dataframe I'm using. For DF %>% str() I get: Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 8460 obs. of  58 variables:

Comment: @JPreisser  So, it is a tibble.  but, it should work if the match is right.  please check my comment below your question.  I think it is because of leading/lagging spaces in the column>

Comment: But when I look at the unique values, all I see is this: [1] NA  "X" "-" How could there be invisible white space?

Comment: @JPreisser  Then, it should work.  What is the column name  and dataset name